# How can I insert an xml comment with Groovy MarkupBuilder?

Tags: xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I would like to insert comments into my xml document with a Groovy MarkupBuilder. How is it possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `mkp.comment` like so:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( writer )
builder.cars {
    mkp.comment "A comment"
    ford( type:'escort')
    ford( type:'fiesta')
 }

println writer
```

Which prints:

```
<cars><!-- A comment -->
  <ford type='escort' />
  <ford type='fiesta' />
</cars>
```

The `mkp.XXX` methods are [described here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try [MarkupBuilderHelper.comment](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilderHelper.html#comment-java.lang.String-%20%20[2]:%20http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-). The linked page has an example.

Uses [getMkp](http://latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html#getMkp--)() to get the `MarkupBuilderHelper`.